# Finding the most frequent combination in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns `From` and `To`, and I need to know the most frequent combination of locations `From` and `To`.

Example:

```
From        To
------------------
Home        Office
Home        Office
Home        Office
Airport     Home
Restaurant  Office
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by the two columns together and count the number of occurrences of each pair, then sort the pairs by this count.

The following code does the job:

```
df.groupby(["From", "To"]).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

and, for the example of the question, it returns:

```
From        To
-----------------------
Home        Office    3
Restaurant  Office    1
Airport     Home      1
```

Answer (score 2):

if the order does matter:

```
df['FROM_TO'] = df['FROM'] + df['TO']

df['COUNT'] = 1

df.groupby(['FROM_TO'])['COUNT'].sum()
```

gives you all the occurrences in one go. Simply take the max to find the largest occurrence.

If the order does matter first sort the values before:

df.loc[:,:] = np.sort(df.values,axis=1)  # if the df only consists of the FROM adn TO columns.

Comment: Thanks @Eddy, appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and [`Series.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)

```
df.groupby('From')['To'].value_counts().idxmax()
```

**Output**

```
('Home', 'Office')
```

in general `groupby.value_counts` is faster than `groupby.size`

Another way:

```
df.apply(tuple, axis=1).value_counts().idxmax()
```

Or

```
df.apply(tuple, axis=1).mode()
```

**Output**

```
0    (Home, Office)
dtype: object
```